# Unable to sign code with code-signing certificate

Tags: code-signing, authenticode, signtool

We purchased the [Microsoft Authenticode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) certificate from Thawte. Now I have it in a PFX file. I try the following:

```
D:\sign>signtool sign /f ./cert/cert.pfx /p mypass /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll "mySetup.exe"
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed and timestamped: mySetup.exe
```

But when I run `mySetup.exe`, it runs like unsigned, and shows "Unknown Publishier".
When I verify the EXE file with SignTool, I get following.

```
D:\sign>SignTool verify mySetup.exe
SignTool Error: WinVerifyTrust returned error: 0x800B010A
SignTool Error: File not valid: mySetup.exe

Number of errors: 1
```

What is wrong?

Comment: UPD: I noticed that when I opening this certificate (I installed it on my system), I see yellow exclamation mark with text: "Windows Does Not Have Enough Information to Verify this Certificate".

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the fact that Thawte uses an Intermediate Certificate for signing. They consider this to be within [best practices](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO2659), which I won't argue one way or the other.

From an end user standpoint, however, this can lead to complications. This is a [known issue with VSTO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970682) (Visual Studio Tools for Office) solutions using ClickOnce, and may be what is affecting you here.

The solution for dealing with this is, sadly, that you will need to add the appropriate Intermediate CA's cert to all end user machines:

> #### Resolution
>
> The workaround to this issue is to include the Intermediate Certificate Authorities’ certificate on all end user machines where the application will be installed. As of now the issue is reported only with the handling of Thawte certificate and would require that Thawte intermediate certificate be installed on the end users machine.

[Thawte provides links to the appropriate CA certs for their Intermediate Certificates](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=AR1384&actp=RELATED_RESOURCE)

Comment: I ran into the same issue while signing with a Thawte certificate. However, it was sufficient to install the Thawte intermediate certificate on the development machine only for that it is accepted. - Thanks a lot for your answer, it showed me the right way to proceed.

Comment: @domkeconsulting or taswyn Is there any possible way this can be an intermittent issue? I had a signing job fail with this exact error code, and when I pulled the commandline straight from the log and re-ran it, it successfully verified o.0

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: Since I installed the Intermediate Certificate, this issue never occured again. I'm signing the deliverables through a call to a batch file in a post-build action. Could it be an issue with the certificate not installed for the user account running the job?